# Deploying TFLite on microcontrollers

Tags: tensorflow, stm32, tensorflow-lite, mbed

I'm trying to deploy TF Lite on a microcontroller that is not in the [examples](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/v2.1.0/tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/examples/hello_world#deploy-to-stm32f746) provided by TF repository, and I'm starting with an STM32L0.

My question is:

1) how can I modify the mbed project for an STMF4 to fit another STM32 family?

I noticed I need to change the TARGET (which I could find in the mbed-os repository) but it returns me a few errors saying it misses AUDIO_DISCO and BSP modules.

2) Where do I find these libraries for my board?

**Specs:**

- Linux Ubuntu 18.04
- mbed cli 1.10.2
- mbed os >= 5 *(contains mbed-os.lib file)*
- tensorflow v2.10.1
- Discovery Kit for STM32L07CZY6TR (B-L072-LRWAN1)

Answer (score 0):

For part #1, you can remove the AUDIO_DISCO and BSP .lib files that are in the generated projects for Mbed.

This should get you something that builds examples that don't need to access the microphone or accelerometers, but if you want to use sensor data, you'll have to figure out what the equivalents are for your board since Mbed OS doesn't offer abstractions for these kinds of devices.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do that by replacing the target flag with my device. The build files were created under my device name!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build for other targets by doing the following:

1. Find the target name for your board in [mbed-os/targets/](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/tree/master/targets)
   In my case it was DISCO_L072CZ_LRWAN1
2. Clone the v2.1.0 of tensorflow repository (the latest version on master didn't work for me)
3. Replace  by your target name in the following command:

   > ```
   > make -f tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/Makefile TARGET=mbed TAGS="CMSIS <lowercase_target>" generate_hello_world_mbed_project
   > ```
4. Follow the next steps described in the tutorial and run the following command with your target name uppercase:

   > ```
   > mbed compile -m <TARGET_UPPERCASE> -t GCC_ARM
   > ```

Done! If you need to use the libraries, they will be located in

> ```
> tensorflow/lite/experimental/micro/tools/make/gen/mbed_cortex-m4/prj/hello_world/mbed/mbed-os/features/
> ```

Hope it helps! =)